# Assigning multi-dimensional Numpy Array to a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

##### Background

I have a `numpy.ndarray` of `shape==(95,15)`. I already have the desired `Series.Index` names, of `len(my_index)==95`. I want to create a `Series` in which every index is associated with one of the rows of my 95x15 `numpy.ndarray`.

##### Variable Names

- `pfit`:     95x15 `numpy.ndarray`
- `my_index`: 95x1 `list(str)`

##### Steps Taken

1. The following fails with corresponding error:

```
my_series = pd.Series(index=my_index, dtype="object", data=pfit)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\gford1\AppData\Local\Temp\1/ipykernel_22244/2329315457.py", line 1, in <module>
    my_series = pd.Series(index=my_index, dtype="object", data=pfit)

  File "C:\Users\gford1\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\series.py", line 439, in __init__
    data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy)

  File "C:\Users\gford1\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\construction.py", line 577, in sanitize_array
    subarr = _sanitize_ndim(subarr, data, dtype, index, allow_2d=allow_2d)

  File "C:\Users\gford1\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\construction.py", line 628, in _sanitize_ndim
    raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional")

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

2. I therefore have to iterate through `my_index` and add the `pfit` arrays, one-by-one:

```
my_series = pd.Series(index=my_index, dtype="object")
i = 0
for idx in my_series.index:
    my_series[idx] = pfit[i]
    i+=1
```

#2 works, but I believe that there is a better / faster way that I am unaware of.

Comment: does `data=list(pfit))` help?

Comment: I want to preserve the numpy array

Comment: I don't think you understand what a `Series` is, or what your iteration does.  Look at `my_series.values`.  Has that "preserved" the array?

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but I do understand what a Series is. I don't want to needlessly convert a C-style Numpy array to a Python linked list (i.e. ``list(pfit)``), to then only again retrieve it as a Numpy array when I need it.

Comment: The only way you can preserved a 2d array in a Series is to put it, whole, into one cell.  You can't put it, one row at a time, into the Series, and still retrieve it as a 2d array.

Comment: If you look at my #2 above, I am able to set a "cell" to a 1D Numpy Array. You have to set the ``dtype==object``, which is somewhat like a C-struct. It contains the amount of bytes and fields within the ``dtype``. This allows you to add a Numpy array to a Pandas Series, somewhat like a C-function with a ``void*`` parameter that the user must handle within the function arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240394/discussion-between-trozzel-and-hpaulj).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [283]: pfit=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [284]: pfit
Out[284]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [285]: my_index=[1,2,3]
```

Your construct:

```
In [286]: my_series = pd.Series(index=my_index, dtype="object")
     ...: i = 0
     ...: for idx in my_series.index:
     ...:     my_series[idx] = pfit[i]
     ...:     i+=1
     ...: 
In [287]: my_series
Out[287]: 
1      [0, 1, 2, 3]
2      [4, 5, 6, 7]
3    [8, 9, 10, 11]
dtype: object
In [288]: my_series.values
Out[288]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])],
      dtype=object)
```

My suggestion produces the same thing:

```
In [289]: list(pfit)
Out[289]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])]
In [290]: S = pd.Series(index=my_index, data=list(pfit))
In [291]: S
Out[291]: 
1      [0, 1, 2, 3]
2      [4, 5, 6, 7]
3    [8, 9, 10, 11]
dtype: object
In [292]: S.values
Out[292]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])],
      dtype=object)
```

recreating the 2d array:

```
In [293]: np.stack(S.values)
Out[293]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Dataframe:

```
In [294]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=my_index, data=pfit)
In [295]: df
Out[295]: 
   0  1   2   3
1  0  1   2   3
2  4  5   6   7
3  8  9  10  11
In [296]: df.values
Out[296]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

===

If I change an element of `pfit`, the change appears in `S` and `df`.

```
In [305]: pfit[1,1] = 100
In [306]: pfit
Out[306]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4, 100,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11]])
In [307]: S
Out[307]: 
1      [0, 1, 2, 3]
2    [4, 100, 6, 7]
3    [8, 9, 10, 11]
dtype: object
In [308]: df
Out[308]: 
   0    1   2   3
1  0    1   2   3
2  4  100   6   7
3  8    9  10  11
```

In the `df` case the `data` array is used directly, without copy or change, as the `_values` attribute (or whatever it's called internally).

In the Series case, `Out[289]` is a list of 1d `views` of `pfit`.  Hence a change to the 2nd view is appears in both.

But recreating a 2d array from the Series, as done with [293] makes a copy, a new 2d array.

We can see this difference by looking at the arrays `ipython` display earlier - though understanding what's going on here also requires an understanding of `numpy` views and object references.

```
In [309]: Out[292]
Out[309]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([  4, 100,   6,   7]),
       array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])], dtype=object)
In [310]: Out[293]
Out[310]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```